# using jquery autocomplete on repeatable fields

Tags: jquery, autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I am currently working on a small script which allows the user to add multiple text fields, here is a screen shot:

[image]

The user starts to fill in each field and then autocomplete kicks in. This works great for the first initial text input. If you add a new one, the authocomplete doesnt work. I first ahve to save the information (by posting the form) and then go back to that field. Autocomplete will then work.

Is there away i can get this to work on the fly?

Here is my jQuery:

```
jQuery(".post_email_repeatable").autocomplete({
    source:"get_posts.php",
    minLength:1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to run the jQuery.autocomplete command on the new input when you click the '+' button to add a new field.

Find the function that is being run when you press the '+' button and add code that looks like this.

```
jQuery(newbutton).autocomplete({
    source:"get_posts.php",
    minLength:1
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It is because the input was not present in the DOM at page load. I would suggest using the .on() method to make sure it kicks in for new inputs. A quick example and [docs](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('focus keyup', '.post_email_repeatbale', function(event){
$(this).autocomplete({
    ...
});
})
```